# Como detectar acesso negado com PHP no Windows?

Tags: php, windows

Estou listando diretórios do Windows com o `scandir()` do `PHP` e alguns diretórios como "System Volume Information", "Documents and Settings" entre outros tem o acesso negado a listagem ao tentar abrir, como poderia fazer uma função para testar se o diretório tem acesso ou não retornando uma variável `true` ou `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, você pode utilizar [`is_readable($caminho)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) para testar se o usuário utilizado para rodar o PHP tem acesso a um arquivo ou diretório.

Exemplo (do manual):

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
if (is_readable($filename)) {
    echo 'The file is readable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not readable';
}
```